# How can I share a Power BI report visual on a website without the bottom navigation bar?

Tags: powerbi

Are there any way to display a Power BI visual on a webpage without either (1) forcing the user to sign in because the report is embedded as "Website or portal", or (2) displaying the bottom most navigation bar that says "Microsoft Power BI", allows the user to change pages and worst of all: has quick-links to share the report on social media, because the report is embedded as "Publish to web (public)"?

Option (1) is not feasible in our case since the website users are not registered in our AD. And option (2) is not feasible because we want the clean charts, not charts with all these controls.

I have tried embedding with the code snippet from the Power BI application, and by loading the visual dynamically with javascript. Neither way seemed to allow disabling the navigation bars.
[image: The bar that should be disabled]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  This is the "[embed for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/powerbi-implementation-planning-usage-scenario-embed-for-your-customers)" embedding scenario.

> This usage scenario focuses on how a developer can programmatically embed Power BI content in a custom application for your customers. (The developer isn't necessarily responsible for creating the Power BI content.) The Embed for your customers scenario applies when the application audience comprises users who don't have permission or appropriate licenses to access Power BI content in your customers. The custom application requires an embedding identity that has permission and an appropriate license to access Power BI content. The custom application could be a multitenancy application.

You can follow the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-customer-app) to get started:

> In this tutorial, you learn how to embed a Power BI report in a .NET 5.0 application, as part of the embed-for-your-customers (also known as an app-owns-data) solution. In an embed-for-your-customers solution, your app users don't need to sign in to Power BI or have a Power BI license.